# Game maker, assigning instance specific solid variable

Tags: instance, game-engine, with-statement, game-maker

The problem I experience with my game occurs when I try to place a instance of an object in the game room. I don't want the instances to overlap so I have have this if statement to check if the place is free `if (place_free(mouse_x, mouse_y))`  as you may know `place_free(x,y)` only check for solid instances collision.
So what I thought I would do is to change the created instance solid variable to true when it have been placed so I can't place a instance on it later on. But to my surprise it changes all instances solid variable to true so I can't place anything more then once because it is checking collision for itself.

The code I use is the following.

```
if (place_free(mouse_x, mouse_y) and mouse_check_button_pressed(mb_left)){
   x = mouse_x;
   y = mouse_y;

   var this;
   this = id;
   with(this){       
      this.solid = true;
      show_debug_message("solid = true")
      show_debug_message(this.solid)
   }
}
```

I don't know what I am doing wrong or why it does not only change the solid variable for the specified instance but I really hope someone in here knows why this does not work and what I need to do instead.

Comment: Where is placed the code (event, object)? How you create instances? P.S. Share your project, it will be fastest way.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply! The instance that exicute this is in the instance that just got created, or in the obj that this instance is created from so to speak. Thats why i thougth i would use the id, so it dose not do it to all instances of that obj but that does not work.

Comment: What event where the code placed?

Comment: Your code you showed is strange. For example, it's same: `if (place_free(mouse_x, mouse_y) and mouse_check_button_pressed(mb_left)) { x = mouse_x; y = mouse_y; solid = true; show_debug_message("solid = true (" + string(id) + ")"); }`. But this code won't do what you want (if I understood you right). It depends on: how you create object, where is the code placed and other things. Share your project then I can see all details and help you.

Comment: I see what you mean but this code just decide if it can be placed or not, its inside a lot of other code that decide other things and the code that creates the instance is in another obj, so i can understand why its hard to work with. But i found a solution anyways, tanks for you'r time tho! it helped me solve the problem! got me thinking in other ways.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution! what i did was to change the collision checking from `place_free(x,y)` to `collision_rectangle( x1, y1, x2, y2, obj, prec, notme )`
and it worked really good!